# My tab bar and navigation controller disappears when i register for account

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, storyboard-reference

I am having some issues with tab bar and navigation controllers. I am new to swift so please bare with me if i don't make sense.
First i have a MAIN storyboard which has a tab bar as the initial view controller. I then have storyboard references that point to other storyboards eg. search, explore etc.

when i register an account on my register view controller which has its own storyboard called AUTH - i want to navigate to the HOME storyboard which has a view controller called HomeFeedViewController. However when i try to accomplish this it takes me to the correct view controller which is the HomeFeedViewController but my tab bar and bottom navigation has disappeared. When i close the app and open again - the navigation and bar appears - what am i doing wrong?

NOTE: my MAIN storyboard has tab bar view controller as initial view controller and my HOME storyboard has a navigation view controller as its initial view controller!

here is my code to navigate to the home feed view controller in my register view controller class:

```
if success {
    let mainSB = UIStoryboard(name: "HomeFeed", bundle: nil)
    let homeVC = mainSB.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeFeedViewController") as! HomeFeedViewController
    homeVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    self.present(homeVC, animated: true)
     print("successfully registered")
       } else {
            let validationAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Sign Up Failed", message: "There was an error registering your account. Please try again.", preferredStyle: .alert)
             validationAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cool", style: .cancel, handler: nil))                  
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should see the full Storyboard logic to give you a better answer, but I think your answer will be somewhere the presentation style.
NOTE: Only a suggestion, but your view hierarchy should be reviewed, because when you log in your homeviewcontoller(you can "pop" back, or you can replace the whole viewstack) should be your rootviewcontroller, and if I understand correctly there is a stack when you click through login. But here is a possible quick fix:

```
homeVC.modalPresentationStyle = .currentContext
```

If it does not help, one of these will:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimodalpresentationstyle

Comment: i have posted a screenshot of the storyboard. This is my top level storyboard - i want to go into the home feed storyboard - how can this be accomplished using storyboard references as displayed

Comment: Ok, now I understand better. The reason you "lost" your tabbar because you present your HomeFeedVC and not the tabbarcontroller. If Auth is a separate VC you can use as an easy solution to present them modally(pop over) and when successfully logged in, just dismiss the view and user goes back to tabbar controller. If the register vc part of the tabbar then on success just change the tabbarindex to 0. But if you are insist for this approach, you have to set up the tabbar as a rootVC again. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40994943/get-out-of-navigation-controller-and-go-back-to-tab-bar-view

Comment: thanks - i needed to set the tab bar as a root vc!